# CSS and JS issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I have problem with that code,  I want to make sidebar when she going in everything is ok but when I press burger button again
the block does not animate.

Code here:
https://pastebin.pl/view/74464f3c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left out your animation keyframes in css, and also a few things in your .hide class, take a look ;) :

```js
const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");

let a = document.querySelector(".nav");
let b = 0;

burger.addEventListener("click", function() {
    burger.classList.toggle("active");


    if (burger.classList.contains("active") == true) {

        document.querySelector(".nav").classList.add("show");
        document.querySelector(".nav").classList.remove("hide");

        b++;
    } else if (b == 1) {
        document.querySelector(".nav").classList.toggle("show");
        document.querySelector(".nav").classList.add("hide");

        b--;
    }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.burger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  transition: .2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger.active {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);

}

.burger span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  left: 0;
  transition: top .2s .2s, bottom .2s .2s, opacity .2s .2s, transform .2s .4s;

}

.burger span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0
}

.burger.active span:nth-child(1) {
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.burger span:nth-child(2) {
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
}

.burger.active span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.burger span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
}

.burger.active span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: calc(50% - 5px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav {
  display: none;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 15vw;
  background-color: #3652f5;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
}

ul,
ul li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {

  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

i {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: white;

}

.icon-home {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.nav.show {
  display: block;
  animation: fadeInLeft .5s linear;
  width: 15vw;

}

.nav.hide {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeOutLeft .5s linear;
  width: 15vw;
}

@keyframes fadeOutLeft {
   0% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0);
   }
   100% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(-15vw);
   }
}

@keyframes fadeInLeft {
   0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(-20px);
   }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0);
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="burger">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
<nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><i class='icon-home'></i></li>
        <li><i class='icon-user'></i></li>
        <li><i class='icon-facebook'></i></li>
        <li><i class='icon-twitter'></i></li>
        <li><i class='icon-linkedin'></i></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```